# Negative Fehling's Test for glyoxal and glyoxylic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry

While I understand why aromatic aldehydes and ketones do not give positive Fehling's test, I do not know why Glyoxal and Glyoxylic Acid give a negative test too. Nothing has been written about these two compounds in my study material and I was hoping someone could help me out with the reasoning. I figure it's something to do with presence of alpha-H but I'm not sure.

Comment: See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/90778/does-acrolein-give-fehlings-test/136835

Comment: I have seen that question, and the answer did not satisfy the user who asked nor did it answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good diagram of the mechanism [here](https://www.chemistrylearner.com/fehlings-solution.html) that I have reproduced below.

The first step is the formation of an enolate anion of the aldehyde by removal of the alpha proton by hydroxide. The enolate then binds to Cu2+. If the enolate cannot be formed then the reaction cannot proceed. Glyoxal and Glyoxylic Acid cannot form enolates so they give a negative test.
The only proton that can be removed from glyoxal to form an enolate is the proton on a -CHO group. They are far less acidic than the alpha protons of an aldehyde. Glyoxalic acid obviously deprotonates at the carboxylic acid group, so no enolate forms.

[image]

Comment: Why can't glyoxal form the enolate?

Comment: @DhruvKaushik I have edited to answer this